# Extract date mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, extract

as a very noob on mysql, I'm wondering how I can get my invoices, dated since more than 16 years.
I need a function that works at all time, so without specifying today's date.

I know it starts by

```
select extract(year from now()...)
```

the "..." being the rest of the function.

[Here' the table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjQiG.png)

I expect the script to fetch all the invoices stored in the database, that are dated since more than 16 years

If you guys need more details I'll be glad to give.

Thanks !

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output corresponding to that input data

Comment: Are you looking for `extract(year from current_date)` (or `year(current_date)`.)

Comment: @jarlh I don't really know, but I need to calculate what year, was the year 16 years ago, and this, also if I run the script in 2035.

Comment: @NicoHaase table structure is a typical payment table such as:
Payment_id as PK
Payment_date
Amount
...


I expect the script to fetch all invoices date since more than 16 years

Comment: So today you want 2007 as result?

Comment: @jarlh, yes for today that would be the result

Answer (score 2):

To get the year 16 years ago:

```
extract(year from current_date - interval'16' year)
```

ANSI SQL compliant way, supported by MySQL.